# Is it true $|x_{n+1}-x_n|< 3^{-n}$ implies $x_n$ converges in $\Bbb R$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $d(x_{n+1},x_n)<\frac{1}{3^n}$, then, is $x_n$ convergent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $m > n$. Then by triangle inequality $$d(x_m,x_n) \leq d(x_m,x_{m-1}) + d(x_{m-1},x_{m-2}) + \cdots + d(x_{n+1},x_n) \\ = \dfrac1{3^{m-1}} + \dfrac1{3^{m-2}} + \cdots + \dfrac1{3^n} < \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \dfrac1{3^k} = \dfrac1{3^n} \dfrac32 = \dfrac1{2 \cdot 3^{n-1}}$$
Use this to prove that the sequence is a Cauchy sequence, and make use of completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ to prove that the sequence converges.

Comment: So given $\epsilon >0$, I may find n such that $1/(2\cdot 3^{n-1})<\epsilon$ and that way I know the difference between any pair of terms after $x_n$ is less than $\epsilon$, right?

Comment: @jack Yes. Thats true. Given $\epsilon > 0$, choosing $N(\epsilon) = -\log_3(2 \epsilon) + 1$, we have that for all $m,n > N(\epsilon)$, $\vert x_m - x_n \vert < \epsilon$. Hence, Cauchy and hence converges.

Answer (score 3):

HINTS: Suppose that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<3^{-n}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $m\in\Bbb N$ be arbitrary; what can you say about $$\sum_{n\ge m}\frac1{3^n}\:?$$ What does this imply about $|x_k-x_n|$ for $k,n\ge m$? Finally, what do you know about Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Thanks for your help as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n+1}-a_{n}|< \infty $ to prove the sequence is Cauchy and hence convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208559/cauchy-sequence-what-is-this-question-actually-telling-me/208576#208576).