# How do I show that the sequence below is a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $(N, \|.\|)$ is a normed space and $(x_n)$ a sequence in $N$ such that
>
> $\|x_n - x_{n+1}\| < \frac{1}{2^n}$
>
> Then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Just a hint on how to prove this will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Here is the [same problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490107/prove-that-a-sequence-is-a-cauchy-sequence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. For $n < m$, we have $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$
\begin{align*}
  \norm{x_n - x_m} &= \norm{\sum_{k=n}^{m-1} x_{k+1} - x_k}\\ 
        &\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \norm{x_{k+1} - x_k}
\end{align*}
Now use what you are given and what you know aobut the geometric series and its partial sums.

Comment: Your sum is < sum 1/2^k k from n to m-1 < sum 1/2^k k from n to infinity =0 and this completes the proof?

Comment: Replace $=0$ and the end with $\to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ ... yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sir.