# verify, that this sequence is cauchy-sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Be $ 0 < q < 1, (a_n)_{n \in  \mathbb{N}} $ a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $ n_0  \in  \mathbb{N} $

One has: $ |a_{n+1} -a_n| \leq q |a_n-a_{n-1}|$

for all $n \geq n_o$. Show, that the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ convergates.

I tryed to verify, that its a Cauchy-sequence, but i didn't gone very far..

Comment: See fixed point theorm.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208559/cauchy-sequence-what-is-this-question-actually-telling-me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

$|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq q^{n-1}|a_2 - a_1|$ (why?)

**Hint 2:**

For $m\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$ $|a_{n+1} - a_{m}| \leq \sum_{k=m}^n|a_{k+1}-a_k|$ by the triangle inequality

**Hint 3:**

For any $\epsilon>0$, we would like to show that there is an $N$ such that $|a_{n+1} - a_{m}|<\epsilon$ whenever $N<m\leq n$.

Now, for a particular choice of $N$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
|a_{n+1} - a_{m}| &\leq \sum_{k=m}^n|a_{k+1}-a_k|\\
&\leq \sum_{k=m}^nq^{k-1}|a_2-a_1|
\\
&\leq \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_2-a_1| q^{k-1}
= |a_2-a_1| q^{N} \sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k\\
&= |a_2-a_1| q^{N} \cdot \frac{1}{1-q}
\end{align}
$$
You may choose an $N$ so that this is less than $\epsilon$ in order to complete your proof.

Comment: Hint 1: i guess, because its given, that $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \leq q |a_{n+1} -a_n|$, so $|a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}| \leq q |a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|$, => $|a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}|\leq q* q |a_{n+1} -a_n|$

Comment: Yes, in other words, you could say it follows from induction.  Now, any idea how to use those two together?

Comment: Sorry, but i still don't have an idea..

Comment: See my latest edit.