# On the possible values of $\sum\varepsilon_na_n$, where $\varepsilon_n=\pm1$ (i.e., changing signs of the original series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I have used the following result in an answer on this site.

---

> Suppose that $a_n>0$ are positive real numbers such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n=+\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. Ten for any choice of $A,B\in\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ such that $A\le B$ there exists a sequence $\varepsilon_n$ such that each $\varepsilon_n\in\{\pm1\}$,
>   $$\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \varepsilon_k a_k=A
> \qquad\text{ and }\qquad
> \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \varepsilon_k a_k=B.$$

In the other words, this says how we can change the behavior of the series by changing the signs of the terms of the series.

*Sketch of the proof.* We choose two sequences such that $A_n\to A$, $B_n\to B$. We construct the sequence $\varepsilon_n$ in blocks.

In the first block we choose $\varepsilon_k=1$ and we stop at the first $n_0$ when $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_1} \varepsilon_ka_k > A_1$.

The second block will have negative signs, and we stop when $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_2} \varepsilon_k a_k < B_1$.

By induction we can continue in choosing blocks with $+1$'s and $-1$'s like this. (I.e. we always have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_{2l-1}} \varepsilon_ka_k > A_l$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_{2l}} \varepsilon_ka_k < B_l$; moreover, the numbers $n_l$ are always chosen in the $l$-th step of the construction as the minimal possible number with these properties.)

The divergence of the original series is used to get that each block ends somewhere. The fact that $a_n\to0$ is used to get that the values of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are indeed $A$ and $B$. $\hspace{2cm}\square$

---

I think that this result is occasionally useful.

What I am asking for is some reference for this result. (I searched a little and did not find one. I did not find a duplicate question on this site, either.) Or any link to a place, where this result is explained in more detail. (Of course, if you wish to do so, you can post a more detailed proof, different proof or some comments related to this result as an answer.)

Answer (score 4):

I think Hugo Steinhaus, Jean-Pierre Kahane, and some others have worked on things related to this.

Try googling "conditionally convergent" along with things like "random series" and/or "Kahane" and/or "Steinhaus".

See also Miller/Schnitzer's 1996 paper [*Measure and category—some non-analogues*](http://www.emis.de/journals/MP/index_elemei/mp07-1/mp07-1-069-078.pdf).