# Show something is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

If I want to show that something is Cauchy, should I show it converges and then show it is Cauchy or should I go at it straight from the definition.  I am just trying to figure out generally what to do for a sequence.

I don't have a concrete example. I am sorry, but like if the question was Prove that this series is Cauchy... How would I go about doing it?

Comment: It depends. ${}{}$

Comment: Different *somethings* will require different techniques. Give a concrete example of what you have in mind.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208559/cauchy-sequence-what-is-this-question-actually-telling-me) for definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule:

- If you know what it converges to, i.e. if what it converges to is obvious, it is often easier to check convergence directly.  For instance, the sequence $1 - \frac{1}{n}$ obviously converges to $1$, and it's easier to check this than it is to check the Cauchy criterion.
- If you have no idea what it converges to, the Cauchy criterion is a valuable tool.  This is for example the most elementary way to show the partial sums of a series converge.

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence does converge, then it is a Cauchy sequence. Be careful, though, that not always does a Cauchy sequence converges. For exemple, the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, but does **not** converge in $]0,1]$. It does converge in $[0,1]$. Search about *completeness* of a topological space (or a metric space, for what it's worth).

Comment: if its a Cauchy sequence it converges. thats a theorem

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology yes, but not in all metric spaces.

Comment: oh okay, I am only dealing with the real numbers and we have not defined metric spaces so I understand.

Comment: Forget the rest of $\mathbb{R}$ exists, look only at $]0,1]$. The sequence does not converge because $0 \notin ]0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a candidate for what the sequence converges to, then it can be easier to show that the sequence converges. If you don't, though, it can be hard to show that a sequence converges just from the definition. In that case it can be easier to use the definition of Cauchy